# fullScreen() broken in Processing P2D when Windows is scaled

Tags: java, windows, processing, fullscreen, renderer

In Processing 4, with the renderer set to P2D, `fullScreen()` does not make the window fullscreen as expected if Windows scaling is set to anything other than 100% (for example at 125%, the window will fill around 3/4 of the screen). `width` and `height` also report resolutions lower than the screen's, even though `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` correctly state that it's 1920x1080.

This issue occurs only in the exported application, not in the Processing editor. It also doesn't happen with the default renderer or when using Processing 3.

I've tried everything I can think of to resolve this - but the only thing I can think of so far is to compare `displayWidth` with `width` (and the same with height) once the program is open, and if they don't match, show a message to the user telling them to switch to windowed mode. I also considered just using `size(displayWidth, displayHeight)`, but I can't work out how to hide the taskbar with that.

Any ideas? I'd really prefer P2D over the default renderer because of performance and shaders...

Thanks!

The example image has the following code:

```
void settings(){

  fullScreen(P2D); }

void setup(){

  background(255,0,0); }
```

[image: Example of incorrect sizing with fullScreen()]

Comment: Did you file a bug report for this? If not: remember to file a bug report.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  unfortunately there's already an [issue](https://github.com/processing/processing4/issues/514) which was created over half a year ago with no progress... And unfortunately I'm far from experienced enough to work out how to fix it!

Comment: of course, it would be unrealistic to expect anyone why uses a program to also know how to _fix_ that program =) But if there is an issue then you can post a comment on it to mention that you also ran into this with the STR for your own use case, so that the maintainters get a notification that there's activity. They're just regular folks too, if an issue falls by the wayside, the best way to surface it is to have activity on it =)